# Flutter "Hint Text" Animation

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

i would like to animtate "**Hint text**" in  "**InputDecoration**". I found "**Animated_text_kit**" which alove to animate text, but i don't know how to implement this in **inputDecoration** - **Hint text**

Here is my **InputDecoration** Code:

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
              enabledBorder: inputBorderDecoration,
              alignLabelWithHint: true,
              focusedBorder: focusedBorder,
              suffixIcon: isWriting
                  ? null
                  : IconButton(
                      icon: Image.asset('assets/images/microphone.png'),
                      color: Colors.black,
                      onPressed: () {
                        print('microphone taped');
                      }),
              hintText: "Message...",
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: AppColor.darkGrey, fontSize: 18),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.2),
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              ),
              contentPadding:
                  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 0),
              filled: true,
              fillColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.3),
            ),
```

Comment: Can you please post what animation are you looking for too?

Comment: @KaushikChandru I would like something like this..  https://i.imgur.com/PXsaNjt.mp4

Comment: not sure if you can use a package for this. But my suggestion will be to create a string variable and add each character with a timer and set state. Assign this string to the hint of the textfield. For example

    `String animHint = "a";`

Then with a timer add another character to animHint like animHint += "b".. 

assign animHint to the hintText like `hintText:animHint`